# Tweenlite Expo is not defined

Tags: gsap

I wrote the following code in my test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#item {

    background:blue;
    color:yellow;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
  var logo = document.getElementById("item");
  TweenLite.to(logo, 2, {left:"542px", backgroundColor:"red", borderBottomColor:"#90e500", color:"white",ease:Expo.easeOut});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="item">thsi is a para</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run it, I get the error message in console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Expo is not defined
>       at window.onload (test.html:16)

How can I use Expo.easeOut?

Answer (score 0):

To do easing, you have to include `EasePack` too:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/easing/EasePack.min.js"></script>
```

(Or use [TweenMax](https://greensock.com/tweenmax) instead, wich includes `CSSPlugin` and `EasePack` among other features.)